# ElasticSearch JEST Client Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I have written an elasticsearch client in java using JEST API. However, I cannot understand how to get the results from the HIT Object. I keep getting null as the result even though I can see the count of the results is correct.

Here is the relevant code, please let me know how I can correct it. Also note that the record in elasticsearch is simply key-value fields. I would ideally like all the key values in the query result.

```
    HttpClientConfig clientConfig = new HttpClientConfig.Builder("http://138.15.170.105:9200")
            .multiThreaded(true).build();
    JestClientFactory factory = new JestClientFactory();
    factory.setHttpClientConfig(clientConfig);
    JestClient client = factory.getObject();

    String query = "{\n" +
            "    \"query\": {\n" +
            "        \"match\": {\n" +
            "            \"table\":\"pcap/abc\"\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "}";
    Search.Builder searchBuilder = new Search.Builder(query).addIndex("sampleIndex").addType("sampleType");
    try {
        SearchResult result = client.execute(searchBuilder.build());
        System.out.println(result.getTotal());

        List<SearchResult.Hit<String, Void>> hits = result.getHits(String.class);
        //THE FOLLOWING GIVES NULL RESULTS
        for(SearchResult.Hit<String,Void> hit: hits)
            System.out.println(hit.source);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Essentially based on my understanding, I believe the problem is parsing the SearchResult.Hit

Comment: Try to print the content with `System.out.println(result.getJsonString())` .

Comment: I just tried getJsonString() works to give me the entire result. I can probably go through them as a JSONArray now and get each value... great! Thanks :)

Comment: One follow up question, the current query does not give me an exact match for "table" = "value", but gives me several values which come close to this value. Is there any way to modify the query to get an exact match?

Comment: For exact matches, you may want to have fields with the `keyword` type, see : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html

Answer (score 0):

I recommend u to can read test Code, it's very useful.
for example

```
result.extractSource().get(0).getAsJsonObject();  
result.extractSource(false).get(0).getAsJsonObject();
result.getSourceAsObject(Comment.class);
```

...

```
/**
 * @author Dogukan Sonmez
 */
public class JestResultTest {
JestResult result = new JestResult(new Gson());

@Test
public void extractGetResource() {
    String response = "{\n" +
            "    \"_index\" : \"twitter\",\n" +
            "    \"_type\" : \"tweet\",\n" +
            "    \"_id\" : \"1\", \n" +
            "    \"_source\" : {\n" +
            "        \"user\" : \"kimchy\",\n" +
            "        \"postDate\" : \"2009-11-15T14:12:12\",\n" +
            "        \"message\" : \"trying out Elastic Search\"\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "}\n";
    result.setJsonMap(new Gson().fromJson(response, Map.class));
    result.setPathToResult("_source");
    Map<String, Object> expectedResultMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    expectedResultMap.put("user", "kimchy");
    expectedResultMap.put("postDate", "2009-11-15T14:12:12");
    expectedResultMap.put("message", "trying out Elastic Search");
    expectedResultMap.put(JestResult.ES_METADATA_ID, "1");
    JsonObject actualResultMap = result.extractSource().get(0).getAsJsonObject();
    assertEquals(expectedResultMap.size(), actualResultMap.entrySet().size());
    for (String key : expectedResultMap.keySet()) {
        assertEquals(expectedResultMap.get(key).toString(), actualResultMap.get(key).getAsString());
    }
}

@Test
public void extractGetResourceWithoutMetadata() {
    String response = "{\n" +
            "    \"_index\" : \"twitter\",\n" +
            "    \"_type\" : \"tweet\",\n" +
            "    \"_id\" : \"1\", \n" +
            "    \"_source\" : {\n" +
            "        \"user\" : \"kimchy\",\n" +
            "        \"postDate\" : \"2009-11-15T14:12:12\",\n" +
            "        \"message\" : \"trying out Elastic Search\"\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "}\n";
    result.setJsonMap(new Gson().fromJson(response, Map.class));
    result.setPathToResult("_source");
    Map<String, Object> expectedResultMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    expectedResultMap.put("user", "kimchy");
    expectedResultMap.put("postDate", "2009-11-15T14:12:12");
    expectedResultMap.put("message", "trying out Elastic Search");
    JsonObject actualResultMap = result.extractSource(false).get(0).getAsJsonObject();
    assertEquals(expectedResultMap.size(), actualResultMap.entrySet().size());
    for (String key : expectedResultMap.keySet()) {
        assertEquals(expectedResultMap.get(key).toString(), actualResultMap.get(key).getAsString());
    }
}

@Test
public void extractGetResourceWithLongId() {
    Long actualId = Integer.MAX_VALUE + 10l;

    String response = "{\n" +
            "    \"_index\" : \"blog\",\n" +
            "    \"_type\" : \"comment\",\n" +
            "    \"_id\" : \"" + actualId.toString() + "\", \n" +
            "    \"_source\" : {\n" +
            "        \"someIdName\" : \"" + actualId.toString() + "\"\n," +
            "        \"message\" : \"trying out Elastic Search\"\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "}\n";
    result.setJsonMap(new Gson().fromJson(response, Map.class));
    result.setPathToResult("_source");
    result.setSucceeded(true);

    Comment actual = result.getSourceAsObject(Comment.class);
    assertNotNull(actual);

    assertEquals(new Long(Integer.MAX_VALUE + 10l), actual.getSomeIdName());
}


@Test
public void extractGetResourceWithLongIdNotInSource() {
    Long actualId = Integer.MAX_VALUE + 10l;

    String response = "{\n" +
            "    \"_index\" : \"blog\",\n" +
            "    \"_type\" : \"comment\",\n" +
            "    \"_id\" : \"" + actualId.toString() + "\", \n" +
            "    \"_source\" : {\n" +
            "        \"message\" : \"trying out Elastic Search\"\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "}\n";
    result.setJsonMap(new Gson().fromJson(response, Map.class));
    result.setPathToResult("_source");
    result.setSucceeded(true);

    SimpleComment actual = result.getSourceAsObject(SimpleComment.class);
    assertNotNull(actual);

    assertEquals(new Long(Integer.MAX_VALUE + 10l), actual.getSomeIdName());
}



@Test
public void extractUnFoundGetResource() {
    String response = "{\"_index\":\"twitter\",\"_type\":\"tweet\",\"_id\":\"13333\",\"exists\":false}";
    result.setJsonMap(new Gson().fromJson(response, Map.class));
    result.setPathToResult("_source");
    List<JsonElement> resultList = result.extractSource();
    assertNotNull(resultList);
    assertEquals(0, resultList.size());
}

@Test
public void getGetSourceAsObject() {
    String response = "{\n" +
            "    \"_index\" : \"twitter\",\n" +
            "    \"_type\" : \"tweet\",\n" +
            "    \"_id\" : \"1\", \n" +
            "    \"_source\" : {\n" +
            "        \"user\" : \"kimchy\",\n" +
            "        \"postDate\" : \"2009-11-15T14:12:12\",\n" +
            "        \"message\" : \"trying out Elastic Search\"\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "}\n";
    result.setJsonMap(new Gson().fromJson(response, Map.class));
    result.setPathToResult("_source");
    result.setSucceeded(true);
    Twitter twitter = result.getSourceAsObject(Twitter.class);
    assertNotNull(twitter);
    assertEquals("kimchy", twitter.getUser());
    assertEquals("trying out Elastic Search", twitter.getMessage());
    assertEquals("2009-11-15T14:12:12", twitter.getPostDate());
}

@Test
public void getGetSourceAsObjectWithoutMetadata() {
    String response = "{\n" +
            "    \"_index\" : \"twitter\",\n" +
            "    \"_type\" : \"tweet\",\n" +
            "    \"_id\" : \"1\", \n" +
            "    \"_source\" : {\n" +
            "        \"user\" : \"kimchy\",\n" +
            "        \"postDate\" : \"2009-11-15T14:12:12\",\n" +
            "        \"message\" : \"trying out Elastic Search\"\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "}\n";
    result.setJsonMap(new Gson().fromJson(response, Map.class));
    result.setPathToResult("_source");
    result.setSucceeded(true);
    Map twitter = result.getSourceAsObject(Map.class, false);
    assertNotNull(twitter);
    assertEquals("kimchy", twitter.get("user"));
    assertEquals("trying out Elastic Search", twitter.get("message"));
    assertEquals("2009-11-15T14:12:12", twitter.get("postDate"));
    assertNull(twitter.get(JestResult.ES_METADATA_ID));
    assertNull(twitter.get(JestResult.ES_METADATA_VERSION));
}

@Test
public void getGetSourceAsString() throws JSONException {
    String response = "{\n" +
            "    \"_index\" : \"twitter\",\n" +
            "    \"_type\" : \"tweet\",\n" +
            "    \"_id\" : \"1\", \n" +
            "    \"_source\" : {\n" +
            "        \"user\" : \"kimchy\",\n" +
            "        \"postDate\" : \"2009-11-15T14:12:12\",\n" +
            "        \"message\" : \"trying out Elastic Search\"\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "}\n";

    result.setJsonMap(new Gson().fromJson(response, Map.class));
    result.setPathToResult("_source");
    result.setSucceeded(true);

    String onlySource = "{" +
            "\"user\":\"kimchy\"," +
            "\"postDate\":\"2009-11-15T14:12:12\"," +
            "\"message\":\"trying out Elastic Search\"" +
            "}";
    JSONAssert.assertEquals(onlySource, result.getSourceAsString(), false);
}

@Test
public void getGetSourceAsStringArray() throws JSONException {
    String response = "{\n" +
            "    \"_index\" : \"twitter\",\n" +
            "    \"_type\" : \"tweet\",\n" +
            "    \"_id\" : \"1\", \n" +
            "    \"_source\" : [" +
            "        { \"user\" : \"kimch\" }, " +
            "        { \"user\" : \"bello\" }," +
            "        { \"user\" : \"ionex\" }" +
            "    ]\n" +
            "}\n";

    result.setJsonMap(new Gson().fromJson(response, Map.class));
    result.setPathToResult("_source");
    result.setSucceeded(true);

    String onlySource = "[" +
            "{\"user\":\"kimch\"}," +
            "{\"user\":\"bello\"}," +
            "{\"user\":\"ionex\"}" +
            "]";
    JSONAssert.assertEquals(onlySource, result.getSourceAsString(), false);
}

@Test
public void getGetSourceAsStringNoResult() {
    String response = "{\n" +
            "    \"_index\" : \"twitter\",\n" +
            "    \"_type\" : \"tweet\",\n" +
            "    \"_id\" : \"1\" \n" +
            "}\n";

    result.setJsonMap(new Gson().fromJson(response, Map.class));
    result.setPathToResult("_source");
    result.setSucceeded(true);
    assertNull(result.getSourceAsString());
}

@Test
public void getUnFoundGetResultAsAnObject() {
    String response = "{\"_index\":\"twitter\",\"_type\":\"tweet\",\"_id\":\"13333\",\"exists\":false}";
    result.setJsonMap(new Gson().fromJson(response, Map.class));
    result.setPathToResult("_source");
    assertNull(result.getSourceAsObject(Twitter.class));
}


@Test
public void extractUnFoundMultiGetResource() {
    String response = "{\n" +
            "\n" +
            "\"docs\":\n" +
            "[\n" +
            "{\"_index\":\"test\",\"_type\":\"type\",\"_id\":\"1\",\"exists\":false},\n" +
            "{\"_index\":\"test\",\"_type\":\"type\",\"_id\":\"2\",\"exists\":false}\n" +
            "]\n" +
            "\n" +
            "}\n";
    result.setJsonMap(new Gson().fromJson(response, Map.class));
    result.setPathToResult("docs/_source");

    List<Map<String, Object>> expected = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    List<JsonElement> actual = result.extractSource();
    assertEquals(expected.size(), actual.size());
}

@Test
public void extractMultiGetWithSourcePartlyFound() {
    String response = "{\"docs\":" +
            "[" +
            "{\"_index\":\"test\",\"_type\":\"type\",\"_id\":\"2\",\"exists\":false},\n" +
            "{\"_index\":\"twitter\",\"_type\":\"tweet\",\"_id\":\"2\",\"_version\":2,\"exists\":true, " +
            "\"_source\" : {\n" +
            "    \"user\" : \"kimchy\",\n" +
            "    \"post_date\" : \"2009-11-15T14:12:12\",\n" +
            "    \"message\" : \"trying out Elastic Search\"\n" +
            "}}" +
            "]}";
    result.setJsonMap(new Gson().fromJson(response, Map.class));
    result.setPathToResult("docs/_source");
    List<Map<String, Object>> expected = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    Map<String, Object> expectedMap1 = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    expectedMap1.put("user", "kimchy");
    expectedMap1.put("post_date", "2009-11-15T14:12:12");
    expectedMap1.put("message", "trying out Elastic Search");
    expected.add(expectedMap1);
    List<JsonElement> actual = result.extractSource();
    assertEquals(expected.size(), actual.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < expected.size(); i++) {
        Map<String, Object> expectedMap = expected.get(i);
        JsonObject actualMap = actual.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
        for (String key : expectedMap.keySet()) {
            assertEquals(expectedMap.get(key).toString(), actualMap.get(key).getAsString());
        }
    }
}

@Test
public void extractMultiGetWithSource() {
    String response = "{\"docs\":" +
            "[" +
            "{\"_index\":\"twitter\",\"_type\":\"tweet\",\"_id\":\"1\",\"_version\":9,\"exists\":true, " +
            "\"_source\" : {\n" +
            "    \"user\" : \"kimchy\",\n" +
            "    \"post_date\" : \"2009-11-15T14:12:12\",\n" +
            "    \"message\" : \"trying out Elastic Search\"\n" +
            "}}," +
            "{\"_index\":\"twitter\",\"_type\":\"tweet\",\"_id\":\"2\",\"_version\":2,\"exists\":true, " +
            "\"_source\" : {\n" +
            "    \"user\" : \"kimchy\",\n" +
            "    \"post_date\" : \"2009-11-15T14:12:12\",\n" +
            "    \"message\" : \"trying out Elastic Search\"\n" +
            "}}" +
            "]}";
    result.setJsonMap(new Gson().fromJson(response, Map.class));
    result.setPathToResult("docs/_source");

    List<Map<String, Object>> expected = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    Map<String, Object> expectedMap1 = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    expectedMap1.put("user", "kimchy");
    expectedMap1.put("post_date", "2009-11-15T14:12:12");
    expectedMap1.put("message", "trying out Elastic Search");

    Map<String, Object> expectedMap2 = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    expectedMap2.put("user", "kimchy");
    expectedMap2.put("post_date", "2009-11-15T14:12:12");
    expectedMap2.put("message", "trying out Elastic Search");

    expected.add(expectedMap1);
    expected.add(expectedMap2);

    List<JsonElement> actual = result.extractSource();

    for (int i = 0; i < expected.size(); i++) {
        Map<String, Object> expectedMap = expected.get(i);
        JsonObject actualMap = actual.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
        for (String key : expectedMap.keySet()) {
            assertEquals(expectedMap.get(key).toString(), actualMap.get(key).getAsString());
        }
    }
}

@Test
public void getMultiGetSourceAsObject() {
    String response = "{\"docs\":" +
            "[" +
            "{\"_index\":\"twitter\",\"_type\":\"tweet\",\"_id\":\"1\",\"_version\":9,\"exists\":true, " +
            "\"_source\" : {\n" +
            "    \"user\" : \"kimchy\",\n" +
            "    \"postDate\" : \"2009-11-15T14:12:12\",\n" +
            "    \"message\" : \"trying out Elastic Search\"\n" +
            "}}," +
            "{\"_index\":\"twitter\",\"_type\":\"tweet\",\"_id\":\"2\",\"_version\":2,\"exists\":true, " +
            "\"_source\" : {\n" +
            "    \"user\" : \"dogukan\",\n" +
            "    \"postDate\" : \"2012\",\n" +
            "    \"message\" : \"My message\"\n" +
            "}}" +
            "]}";
    result.setJsonMap(new Gson().fromJson(response, Map.class));
    result.setPathToResult("docs/_source");
    result.setSucceeded(true);

    List<Twitter> twitterList = result.getSourceAsObjectList(Twitter.class);

    assertEquals(2, twitterList.size());

    assertEquals("kimchy", twitterList.get(0).getUser());
    assertEquals("trying out Elastic Search", twitterList.get(0).getMessage());
    assertEquals("2009-11-15T14:12:12", twitterList.get(0).getPostDate());

    assertEquals("dogukan", twitterList.get(1).getUser());
    assertEquals("My message", twitterList.get(1).getMessage());
    assertEquals("2012", twitterList.get(1).getPostDate());
}

@Test
public void getUnFoundMultiGetSourceAsObject() {
    String response = "{\n" +
            "\n" +
            "\"docs\":\n" +
            "[\n" +
            "{\"_index\":\"test\",\"_type\":\"type\",\"_id\":\"1\",\"exists\":false},\n" +
            "{\"_index\":\"test\",\"_type\":\"type\",\"_id\":\"2\",\"exists\":false}\n" +
            "]\n" +
            "\n" +
            "}\n";
    result.setJsonMap(new Gson().fromJson(response, Map.class));
    result.setPathToResult("docs/_source");
    result.setSucceeded(true);
    List<Twitter> twitterList = result.getSourceAsObjectList(Twitter.class);
    assertEquals(0, twitterList.size());
}


@Test
public void extractEmptySearchSource() {
    String response = "{\"took\":60,\"timed_out\":false,\"_shards\":{\"total\":1,\"successful\":1," +
            "\"failed\":0},\"hits\":{\"total\":0,\"max_score\":null,\"hits\":[]}}";
    result.setJsonMap(new Gson().fromJson(response, Map.class));
    result.setPathToResult("hits/hits/_source");
    List<Map<String, Object>> expected = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    List<JsonElement> actual = result.extractSource();
    assertEquals(expected.size(), actual.size());
}

@Test
public void extractSearchSource() {
    String response = "{\n" +
            "    \"_shards\":{\n" +
            "        \"total\" : 5,\n" +
            "        \"successful\" : 5,\n" +
            "        \"failed\" : 0\n" +
            "    },\n" +
            "    \"hits\":{\n" +
            "        \"total\" : 1,\n" +
            "        \"hits\" : [\n" +
            "            {\n" +
            "                \"_index\" : \"twitter\",\n" +
            "                \"_type\" : \"tweet\",\n" +
            "                \"_id\" : \"1\", \n" +
            "                \"_version\" : \"2\", \n" +
            "                \"_source\" : {\n" +
            "                    \"user\" : \"kimchy\",\n" +
            "                    \"postDate\" : \"2009-11-15T14:12:12\",\n" +
            "                    \"message\" : \"trying out Elastic Search\"\n" +
            "                }\n" +
            "            }\n" +
            "        ]\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "}";
    result.setJsonMap(new Gson().fromJson(response, Map.class));
    result.setPathToResult("hits/hits/_source");
    Map<String, Object> expectedResultMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    expectedResultMap.put("user", "kimchy");
    expectedResultMap.put("postDate", "2009-11-15T14:12:12");
    expectedResultMap.put("message", "trying out Elastic Search");
    JsonObject actualResultMap = result.extractSource().get(0).getAsJsonObject();
    assertEquals(expectedResultMap.size() + 2, actualResultMap.entrySet().size());
    for (String key : expectedResultMap.keySet()) {
        assertEquals(expectedResultMap.get(key).toString(), actualResultMap.get(key).getAsString());
    }
}

@Test
public void getSearchSourceAsObject() {
    String response = "{\n" +
            "    \"_shards\":{\n" +
            "        \"total\" : 5,\n" +
            "        \"successful\" : 5,\n" +
            "        \"failed\" : 0\n" +
            "    },\n" +
            "    \"hits\":{\n" +
            "        \"total\" : 1,\n" +
            "        \"hits\" : [\n" +
            "            {\n" +
            "                \"_index\" : \"twitter\",\n" +
            "                \"_type\" : \"tweet\",\n" +
            "                \"_id\" : \"1\", \n" +
            "                \"_source\" : {\n" +
            "                    \"user\" : \"kimchy\",\n" +
            "                    \"postDate\" : \"2009-11-15T14:12:12\",\n" +
            "                    \"message\" : \"trying out Elastic Search\"\n" +
            "                }\n" +
            "            },\n" +
            "            {\n" +
            "                \"_index\" : \"twitter\",\n" +
            "                \"_type\" : \"tweet\",\n" +
            "                \"_id\" : \"1\", \n" +
            "                \"_source\" : {\n" +
            "                    \"user\" : \"dogukan\",\n" +
            "                    \"postDate\" : \"2012\",\n" +
            "                    \"message\" : \"My Search Result\"\n" +
            "                }\n" +
            "            }\n" +
            "        ]\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "}";
    result.setJsonMap(new Gson().fromJson(response, Map.class));
    result.setPathToResult("hits/hits/_source");
    result.setSucceeded(true);
    List<Twitter> twitterList = result.getSourceAsObjectList(Twitter.class);
    assertEquals(2, twitterList.size());
    assertEquals("kimchy", twitterList.get(0).getUser());
    assertEquals("trying out Elastic Search", twitterList.get(0).getMessage());
    assertEquals("2009-11-15T14:12:12", twitterList.get(0).getPostDate());
    assertEquals("dogukan", twitterList.get(1).getUser());
    assertEquals("My Search Result", twitterList.get(1).getMessage());
    assertEquals("2012", twitterList.get(1).getPostDate());
}

@Test
public void getSearchSourceAsObjectWithoutMetadata() {
    String response = "{\n" +
            "    \"_shards\":{\n" +
            "        \"total\" : 5,\n" +
            "        \"successful\" : 5,\n" +
            "        \"failed\" : 0\n" +
            "    },\n" +
            "    \"hits\":{\n" +
            "        \"total\" : 1,\n" +
            "        \"hits\" : [\n" +
            "            {\n" +
            "                \"_index\" : \"twitter\",\n" +
            "                \"_type\" : \"tweet\",\n" +
            "                \"_id\" : \"1\", \n" +
            "                \"_source\" : {\n" +
            "                    \"user\" : \"kimchy\",\n" +
            "                    \"postDate\" : \"2009-11-15T14:12:12\",\n" +
            "                    \"message\" : \"trying out Elastic Search\"\n" +
            "                }\n" +
            "            }\n" +
            "        ]\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "}";
    result.setJsonMap(new Gson().fromJson(response, Map.class));
    result.setPathToResult("hits/hits/_source");
    result.setSucceeded(true);
    List<Map> twitterList = result.getSourceAsObjectList(Map.class, false);
    assertEquals(1, twitterList.size());
    assertEquals("kimchy", twitterList.get(0).get("user"));
    assertEquals("trying out Elastic Search", twitterList.get(0).get("message"));
    assertEquals("2009-11-15T14:12:12", twitterList.get(0).get("postDate"));
    assertNull(twitterList.get(0).get(JestResult.ES_METADATA_ID));
    assertNull(twitterList.get(0).get(JestResult.ES_METADATA_VERSION));
}


@Test
public void extractIndexSource() {
    String response = "{\n" +
            "    \"ok\" : true,\n" +
            "    \"_index\" : \"twitter\",\n" +
            "    \"_type\" : \"tweet\",\n" +
            "    \"_id\" : \"1\"\n" +
            "}\n";
    result.setJsonMap(new Gson().fromJson(response, Map.class));
    List<Map<String, Object>> expected = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    Map<String, Object> expectedMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    expectedMap.put("ok", true);
    expectedMap.put("_index", "twitter");
    expectedMap.put("_type", "tweet");
    expectedMap.put("_id", "1");
    expected.add(expectedMap);
    List<JsonElement> actual = result.extractSource();
    for (int i = 0; i < expected.size(); i++) {
        Map<String, Object> map = expected.get(i);
        JsonObject actualMap = actual.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
        for (String key : map.keySet()) {
            assertEquals(map.get(key).toString(), actualMap.get(key).getAsString());
        }
    }
}

@Test
public void extractCountResult() {
    String response = "{\n" +
            "    \"count\" : 1,\n" +
            "    \"_shards\" : {\n" +
            "        \"total\" : 5,\n" +
            "        \"successful\" : 5,\n" +
            "        \"failed\" : 0\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "}\n";
    result.setJsonMap(new Gson().fromJson(response, Map.class));
    result.setPathToResult("count");
    Double actual = result.extractSource().get(0).getAsDouble();
    assertEquals(1.0, actual, 0.01);
}

@Test
public void getCountSourceAsObject() {
    String response = "{\n" +
            "    \"count\" : 1,\n" +
            "    \"_shards\" : {\n" +
            "        \"total\" : 5,\n" +
            "        \"successful\" : 5,\n" +
            "        \"failed\" : 0\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "}\n";
    result.setJsonMap(new Gson().fromJson(response, Map.class));
    result.setPathToResult("count");
    result.setSucceeded(true);
    Double count = result.getSourceAsObject(Double.class);
    assertEquals(1.0, count, 0.01);
}

@Test
public void getKeysWithPathToResult() {
    result.setPathToResult("_source");
    String[] expected = {"_source"};
    String[] actual = result.getKeys();
    assertEquals(1, actual.length);
    assertEquals(expected[0], actual[0]);
}

@Test
public void getKeysWithoutPathToResult() {
    assertNull(result.getKeys());
}

class Twitter {
    String user;

    String postDate;

    String message;

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getPostDate() {
        return postDate;
    }

    public void setPostDate(String postDate) {
        this.postDate = postDate;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}

abstract class Base {

    @JestId
    Long someIdName;

    public Long getSomeIdName() {
        return someIdName;
    }

    public void setSomeIdName(Long someIdName) {
        this.someIdName = someIdName;
    }
}

class Comment extends Base {
    String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}

class SimpleComment {

    @JestId
    Long someIdName;

    String message;

    public Long getSomeIdName() {
        return someIdName;
    }

    public void setSomeIdName(Long someIdName) {
        this.someIdName = someIdName;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
}
```